# create jquery cookie on form submit, then display it on the next page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for some example code that does this, but am not having much luck.

I'd greatly appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a jquery plugin for cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt), however I think it can be easier with just javascript per se (not using the jquery library I mean)